# Authorized_Keys file reverts to a unrecoginzed SSH public key!

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, keys

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Kernel: 4.15.0-99-generic)

I recently started using SSH Keys on my Ubuntu server. 
After every reboot of my server my public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is changed to a unrecognized public key.

Other details: My Public key is an **Ed25519**. I've changed the permissions of ~/.ssh on the server to 700. The file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys has a mode of 600. Password is disabled.

Comment: Are you saying that the contents of the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file are being changed, or that your server stops accepting keys of type `ssh-ed25519`?

Comment: The contents of the file are being changed, which results in failing when I try to SSH into the server.

Answer (score 1):

This was because my Ubuntu server was hacked. Someone got into my server and installed a script that automatically installed new keys and removed the ones I installed.

I re-installed the system as the entire server was compromised.